# Wait - Notify working?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is the code I have written, to test the working of `wait()` and `notify()`.
Now I have a bunch of doubts.

```
class A extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    try {
      wait();
      for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        sleep(500);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    System.out.println("End Of Thread");
  }
}

class ThreadWaitNotify {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      A t = new A();
      t.start();
      t.wait();
      t.notify();
      t.join();
      System.out.println("End Of Main");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}
```

My questions are:

1. When I write `t.wait()`  in main, the main does not execute further,
   and I am not able to resume it further. How to do that?
2. Secondly I have written `wait()` in thread also,
   due to which it only prints "End Of Thread", not the loop? Even if I `notify()` from main or not...
3. Now if I write `notify()` in main it does not complete execution.
   While on commenting that line it finishes execution and prints "End Of Main".

Comment: What **do** you know abut `wait()` and `notify()`? I'm not trying to sound nasty, but your questions make it look like your expectations of those methods are **way off**. What do you expect a call to `wait()` to do?

Comment: And: ***never*** write empty `catch` blocks: you're actively *hiding* information that could help you find out the problem. Put *at least*  an `e.printStackTrace()` in *both* catch-blocks.

Comment: You should never call wait() or notify() an a thread. It won't do what you expect. When you perform a notify on a object, you should alter some state asscoiated with it, and when you perform a wait on an object, you should check the same state.

Comment: Joachim Sauer: according to me wait() leaves the cpu and unless notified does not ask for...
so when i notify() it should resume...??

Comment: @sid15g: that's *basically* right. So knowing that, if your *main* thread calls `wait()` and *nothing else* calls `notify()`, then why should the main thread ever continue? The important thing to realize that it's *always* the *current* thread that's waiting and it's waiting for someone to *call `notify()` on the same object you called `wait()` on*. Therefore calling those methods on a Thread object is confusing at best, because it doesn't actually *do anything with that thread*, but with the *current* thread instead.

Comment: Oh, and @sid15g: if someone edits your question to make it more readable and removes some typos in the process, please don't rollback that edit unless they changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I think I got your point... there is no point using wait() in main().

And sorry for the rollback, I am new, and the question page to me looked weird with cuts and red marks... so got confused...

Answer (score 2):

> *My questions are:*
>
> *When I write t.wait() in main, the main does not execute further, and I am not able to resume it further. How to do that?*

The thread that is running main does not hold the lock on `t` when it calls `t.wait()`. As you'll see from the JavaDoc for [wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()):

> **Throws**: IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor.

So your call to wait() is resulting in the IllegalMonitorStateException being thrown. Your empty catch block simply discards the error, which makes it difficult to debug.
You can show the error using `ex.printStackTrace()`; or you can re-throw it as an unchecked exception:

```
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
```

To fix the wait() call, you'd need to synchronize on t:

```
synchronized (t) {
    t.wait();
}
```

You'll also need to hold the same lock when you call notify().

> *Secondly I have written wait() in thread also, due to which it only prints "End Of Thread", not the loop? Even if I notify() from main or not...*

Same thing is happening here, but in a different thread. The new thread that you create doesn't own the lock on t, so the `wait()` call throws an Exception. Again, you're discarding the exception, by not handling it correctly.

> *Now if I write notify() in main it does not complete execution. While on commenting that line it finishes execution and prints "End Of Main".*

I assume you mean "commenting out the calls to wait() and notify()". This is expected. The run() method has finished, that is: it caught the IllegalMonitorStateException that was thrown and carried on to the end of the method. The join() method returns when the thread has finished executing. This happens almost immediately, because the wait() call throws an exception immediately.

Comment: Thanks...

My biggest mistake was i should not have written empty catch block...
that could have solved my problem...

Comment: A similar gotcha (which isn't directly related to your question), is expecting `catch (Exception ex)` to catch anything that gets thrown. It doesn't, because it won't catch Error classes. If you ever find yourself confused about why a line in your code isn't executing, you might consider `catch (Throwable t)`, at least while your investigating a problem.

Comment: @MartinEllis: but then again, an `Error` that falls through usually get's dumped to System.out, so you'll usually *see* it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yep, if it's just a console app, it'll go to System.err. But in my experience, at least, there are still some badly behaved application servers and other 'containers' that will happily swallow them. And for some applications, you're watching logs, and not the terminal.